# Relation between area bounded by two curves

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, area

I have to find the relation between the curve area of the curve bounded by $y=e^{x^2}$, $x-$axis, and the lines $x=1$ and $x =2 $ and the area bounded by the curve $y = \sqrt{\ln(x)}, y-$axis, and the lines $y = e$, $y=e^4$

---

So here's what I did so far, I have $$a = \int_1^2e^{x^2}dx$$ and $$A = \int_e^ {e{^4}}\sqrt{\ln x}dy$$

Now I seem so close, but I just cant seem to be able to relate the 2nd integral whose value is $A$ to the 1st integral. What should I substitute here? Because I'm having a function of $x$ as the integrand and the differential is with respect to $y$. I assume a substitution has to be done here which I'm just not getting.

I want to be able to transform the 2nd integral into a form of the first so that they can be easily relatable which I think is possible, just cant seem to get it. The question asks me to relate the values of $A$ and $a$.

Comment: These are two different questions?

Comment: No, the question is to relate the value of $A$, and $a$, I'm clarifying that in an edit

Comment: Off topic query: Are you a JEE aspirant?

Comment: @RiverX15 Yep I am haha

Comment: @RiverX15  everyone is nowadays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating by parts we have

$$a=\int_{1}^{2}e^{x^2}dx=\left[xe^{x^2}\right]_{1}^{2}-\int_{1}^{2}(2xe^{x^2})xdx$$
$$=2e^4-e-\int_{1}^{2}x(2xe^{x^2})dx$$

and now substitute $u=e^{x^2},$ $du=2xe^{x^2}dx$.

Comment: Okay, I've done that. Can you tell me the expression for $A$ which is the area between the curve $y = \sqrt \ln x$, y axis, and the lines $y = e, y = e^4$? I'm getting confused. Is the area under a curve and  y axis $= \int xdy$ ??

Comment: The expression for $A$ is $A=\int_{e}^{e^4}\sqrt{\ln(x)}d\color{red}{x}$

Comment: The question asks me to find the area between the curve and the $y$ axis. Is that a mistake in the question then? Because graphing $y =\sqrt \ln x $ between the lines $y = e, y = e^4$ doesnt give an area under the y-axis

Comment: Yes, maybe there is a mistake in the question, where is it from? Or try to write it in  terms of x, as Vega said.

Comment: Its a book for preparation of an exam from my country. What I think you're doing is finding the area between $y = \sqrt \ln x$, $x=e, y = e^4$, and the $\color{red}{x}$ axis, and graphing it in desmos does show that $y = \sqrt \ln x$ doesnt give an area between the given lines and $\color{red}{y}$  axis at all. Could you please confirm this?

Comment: @Techie5879 Not all integrals can be found.

Comment: @Techie5879 Yes, there is a some typo, it should be as you said but with $\color{red}{x}=e^{4}$, or $x=\sqrt{\ln y}$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think you have a typo... it should be $x = \sqrt{\ln y}$. When you draw the two regions, you easily conclude that they form a rectangle. Hence, the sum of the two areas is equal to the area of that rectangle ($(2-1)\times (e^4-e) = e^4-e$).

Comment: Nope. That is the equation, and the relation between $A$ and $a$ is given as $A = 2e^4-e-a$
There is no typo

Comment: The question says to find the area between $y = \sqrt \ln (x)$, the y-axis and the lines $y = e, y = e^4$, which is taken as $A$

So, I have $A = \int_e ^{e^4}ydy = \int_e ^{e^4} \sqrt \ln x dy$

Comment: @Techie5879 $\int_e^{e^4} \sqrt{\ln x} \,dy$ makes no sense.

Comment: Okay, so my mistake might be in that part. Can you tell me what the expression for the area under the curve $y=\sqrt \ln x$, y axis, and the lines $y = e$ and $y = e^4$ is?

Comment: @Techie5879 if you are preparing for some exam, what you should do is to find the inverse function of $y=\sqrt{\ln x}$ and then you can find the area the function makes with y-axis. The inverse is $e^{y^{2}}=x$ and now go ahead and find area it makes with the y-axis. Something like $\int_{e}^{e^{4}}e^{y^{2}}\ dy$, if I get your question preperly.

Comment: Yes, I think you're correct then. I think the question in the book does have a typo. But I think there's still a mistake in your answer, as you considered the height of the rectangle to be $e^4$ and not $e^4-e$ (because the lower limit is y=e)

Comment: @Techie5879 yes, I'll correct it.